# microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered even already install

Tags: excel, database, vb.net

i just want to ask about Visual studio doesn't detect my microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0..

last month i write a code to import from excel into database using VB.NET and it worked..
but after a month i open back my coding and try the system but it said that "microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered" even though i already install microsoft access database engine 2010 before..

i never change a little bit of my coding..i just left it but now it doesn't work like before

is there any particular update or something that make it doesn't work??

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your target cpu in your project properties. go to solution explorer<properties<Compile uncheck the prefer 32-bit or change to x64. It works for me, if it doesn`t work try searching a bit more iirc that question is already answered but i cant remember if it is in stackoverflow or other website, which has many suggestions

Comment: Thank you .. this solution for my question.. it went well after checking unchecking prefer 32-bit...thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Access engine can be installed as either 32-bit or 64-bit.  As the other answer notes, it is important to make sure that your application matches the bitness of Access.  You can check on installed OleDB providers by checking the Windows registry; you would need to search on all of the keys in HKCR/CLSID (under Wow6432Node for 32-bit), looking for entries with a value named OLEDB_SERVICES.  Keys with this value will have the provider name as the default value.  This (obviously) isn't practical to do manually, but it should be fairly straightforward to do programmatically.